# Program, run as admin, can't write log file to folder with admin-only ACLs

Tags: windows-10, powershell, acl

I have a folder set up on all of our computers for random log files, configs, etc., deployed with the following PowerShell:

```
#Create directory if it does not already exist
$path = "C:\Wagner"
[System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($path)

#Remove inheritance 
$acl = Get-Acl $path
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)

#Allow SYSTEM access
$System = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new(
  "SYSTEM",
  "FullControl",
  "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", # inheritanceFlags
  "InheritOnly", # propagationFlags
  "Allow"
)
$acl.SetAccessRule($System)

#Allow Admin access
$Admins = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new(
  "BUILTIN\Administrators",
  "FullControl",
  "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", # inheritanceFlags
  "InheritOnly", # propagationFlags
  "Allow"
)
$acl.SetAccessRule($Admins)

$acl | Set-Acl $path
```

If I check the ACLs on an example computer, everything looks correct to me:

```
PS C:\> (Get-ACL C:\Wagner).Access

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly
```

However, if I remote into said machine and try to install a program (in this case, Tableau), I get error `-2147023274`, which I believe means it was unable to write the log file.

```
.\TableauDesktop-64bit-2022-4-0.exe /quiet /norestart /log "c:\Wagner\tableauDesktopInstall.log" ACCEPTEULA=1 ACTIVATE_KEY="****-****-****" REMOVEINSTALLEDAPP=1
```

The above is the command I'm running (in an elevated PowerShell window), and checking `$LASTEXITCODE` gives me `-2147023274`.

If I run the command again, without the `/log`, the program installs successfully. Is there something wrong with my ACLs? This is all on Windows 10 machines.

Comment: I don’t know about your script. But the built-in Admin account is disabled and should remain disabled.  Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: @EmilioGarcia - Verify if you still have a problems if you add Domain Administrators instead of the `BuiltIn\Administrators` which is local Administrator on the machine (not necessarily the built-in Administrator)

Comment: @John `BuiltIn\Administrators` is a user group not a User. The fully qualified name is "Administrators" and refers to the local Administrator group on the machine itself.

Comment: I do not have such a group here (checked) so I thought the OP mean the built-in Admin.  Some misconception on my part apparently. Thanks.

Comment: @EmilioGarcia try and create a file in that folder directly, like `"test" | Out-File "c:\Wagner\test.txt"` and see if you get a better error message? If you can do it, the installer can too. Could that log file already exist - locked by some process?